# Passing C++ pointer as argument into Cython function

Tags: python, cython

```
cdef extern from "Foo.h":
    cdef cppclass Bar:
        pass

cdef class PyClass:
    cdef Bar *bar

    def __cinit__(self, Bar *b)
        bar = b
```

This will always give me something like:
    `Cannot convert Python object argument to type 'Bar *'`

Is there a way to accomplish this, or do I need to extract everything from a `Bar` object, create a Python equivalent, pass it in, then reconstruct it in `PyClass`?

Answer (score 10):

I came across this problem trying to wrap C code with structs as python classes. The issue seems to be that "special" function including `__init__` and `__cinit__` must be declared as `def` rather than `cdef`. This means that they can be called from normal python, so the type parameters are effectively ignored and everything is treated as object.

In J.F. Sebastian's answer the fix is not the wrapping - a double is a basic numeric type and so there is a default conversion between the C/C++ type and the Python object. Czarek's answer is basically correct - you need to use a fake constructor idiom, using a global function. It is not possible to use a @staticmethod decorator as they cannot be applied to cdef functions. The answer looks simpler on the original example provided.

```
cdef extern from "Foo.h":
    cdef cppclass Bar:
        pass

cdef class PyClass:
    cdef Bar *bar

cdef PyClass_Init(Bar *b):
    result = PyClass()
    result.bar = b
    return result
```

Comment: On recent versions of Cython (as of 0.22 at least), the @staticmethod decorator can be applied on cdef functions, so one can now make the global creator function into a static class one for a neater organisation.

Comment: `Bar` c++ class is not a basic numeric type and there is no default conversion.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Could you explain what you mean? Bar does not have to be a basic numeric type in order to store a pointer to it.

Comment: @Amoss: my answer wraps `Bar`. You said: *"In J.F. Sebastian's answer the fix is not the wrapping - a double is a basic numeric type and so there is a default conversion between the C/C++ type and the Python object."* My answer is about wrapping. As you said: you can't pass C++ pointer to a `def` function.

Comment: In your solution the wrapping is unnecessary, and you have demonstrated it on a parameter that has a default promotion anyway. Adding the fake constructor is sufficient to solve the problem without wrapping the c++ class.

Answer (score 8):

As of [Cython 0.21](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/CHANGES.rst#021-2014-09-10) it has been possible to declare `cdef` methods with the `@staticmethod` decorator. This allows static creator methods that take non-Python arguments:

```
cdef extern from "Foo.h":
    cdef cppclass Bar:
        pass

cdef class PyClass:
    cdef Bar *bar

    @staticmethod
    cdef create(Bar *bar):
        cdef PyClass pc = PyClass()
        pc.bar = bar
        return pc
```

Answer (score 5):

For each cdef class create a global cdef function that acts as a constructor, CefResponse is a C++ object, PyResponse a python equivalent of a c++ object:

```
cdef object CreatePyResponse(CefRefPtr[CefResponse] cefResponse):

    pyResponse = PyResponse()
    pyResponse.cefResponse = cefResponse
    return pyResponse

cdef class PyResponse:

    cdef CefRefPtr[CefResponse] cefResponse

    def GetStatus(self):

        return (<CefResponse*>(self.cefResponse.get())).GetStatus()
```

So instead of `resp = PyResponse(cppObject)` call `resp = CreatePyResponse(cppObject)`.

Example taken from CEF Python:
https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/source/browse/cefpython/response.pyx?r=0250b65e046a

Answer (score 1):

Python class accepts Python arguments. To pass a C++ argument you need to wrap it:

```
# distutils: language = c++

cdef extern from "Foo.h" namespace "baz":
    cdef cppclass Bar:
         Bar(double d)
         double get()

cdef class PyBar: # wrap Bar class
    cdef Bar *thisptr
    def __cinit__(self, double d):
        self.thisptr = new Bar(d)
    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr
    property d:
        def __get__(self):
            return self.thisptr.get()
```

`PyBar` instances can be used as any other Python objects both from Cython and pure Python:

```
class PyClass:
    def __init__(self, PyBar bar):
        self.bar = bar

print(PyClass(PyBar(1)).bar.d)
```

Comment: @ChrisArndt: Are you claiming that PyClass accepts `bar` by value?

Comment: No, I'm saying that the class constructor does not take a C pointer, which is what the OP wanted to achieve. BTW, there is (maybe added since this question was raised) a section in the manual, which addresses this specific problem: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#existing-pointers-instantiation Here is how implemented that: https://github.com/SpotlightKid/jack_mixer/blob/e2f0c95779e11378613fa9490a25115ef3608066/_jack_mixer.pyx#L159

Comment: @ChrisArndt: do you understand that you can't pass a C pointer to a `def` method without wrapping it?