# convert python object to cython pointer

Tags: cython

I'm trying to expose c++ classes to python using cython. I wrote their definitions in *.pxd file and implemented a wrappers in *.pyx files. But I got stuck trying to pass to a function pointer to the extension type. Here is simplified example.

**foo.pyx**

```cython
from c_foo cimport cFoo
cdef class Foo:
    cdef cFoo* _impl
```

**c_foo_holder.pxd**

```c
cdef extern from "FooHolder.h":
    cdef cppclass cFooHolder:
        cFooHolder(cFoo* foo)
```

**foo_holder.pyx**

```cython
from c_foo_holder cimport cFooHolder
from c_foo cimport cFoo

cdef class FooHolder:
    cdef cFooHolder* _impl
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self._impl = new cFooHolder(<cFoo*>(foo._impl)) # error here
```

But on the last line I get error "**Python objects cannot be cast to pointers of primitive types**". I also tried several other approaches, but nothing worked:

```cython
# error: 'Foo' is not a type identifier 
from foo import Foo
def __init__(self, Foo foo):
    self._impl = new cFooHolder(foo._impl)

# error: 'Foo' is not a type identifier 
def __init__(self, foo):
   self._impl = new cFooHolder(<Foo>(foo)._impl)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. You have to tell cython that foo._impl is really cFoo* instance. That can be achieved by providing Foo definition (e.g. in foo.pxd). Afterwards you are able to cast python object to Foo and cython will know that its _impl field has type cFoo*.

**foo.pxd**

```cython
from c_foo cimport cFoo
cdef class Foo:
    cdef cFoo* _impl
```

**foo.pyx**

```cython
from c_foo cimport cFoo
cdef class Foo:
    # methods implementation
```

**c_foo_holder.pxd**

```c
cdef extern from "FooHolder.h":
    cdef cppclass cFooHolder:
        cFooHolder(cFoo* foo)
```

**foo_holder.pyx**

```cython
from c_foo_holder cimport cFooHolder
from c_foo cimport cFoo
from foo cimport Foo

cdef class FooHolder:
    cdef cFooHolder* _impl
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self._impl = new cFooHolder((<Foo?>foo)._impl)
```

Answer (score 0):

`__init__` constructor can accept only pure python objects, there is also `__cinit__` but it can accept only C primitive types.

When you pass Foo to `__init__` it cannot see the `_impl` member, only members of python types can be seen.

The solution would be to pass `cFoo*` explicitly to an `Init()` method which emulates a constructor:

```
cdef class FooHolder:
    cdef cFooHolder* _impl
    cdef void Init(self, cFoo* foo_impl):
        self._impl = new cFooHolder(foo_impl)
```

Call it this way:

```
fooHolder = new FooHolder()
fooHolder.Init(foo._impl)
```

Comment: Seems, that I can't do that either while foo is a python object. Am I missing something? I get 'cannot convert Python object argument to type 'cFoo *' if I define function with 'def', and I can't call it from python if I define it with 'cdef'.

Comment: @DikobrAz Hmm seems that you can't call cdef methods outside of a class, try setting class members through a global function instead of an `Init()` method,  see this example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12205374/623622

Comment: No luck. To my knowledge, I can't call cdef members from python at all, they are accessible only inside cython module. And I can't (don't know how) convert python object to cython pointer, so that is actually the problem.

Comment: @DikobrAz You can't call cdef functions from python.