# Cython: C class 'myclass' is declared but not defined

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

I'm trying to create a module in Python that written with Cython. The module planned to use C++ library to provide this to diffrent Python and Cython modules.

The problem is:

```
(base) $ python setup.py build
Compiling queue/myqueue.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing queue/myqueue.pyx

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
# cython: language_level=3

from queue.myqueue import myclass
from queue.myqueue cimport myclass

cdef class myclass:
    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

queue/myqueue.pyx:6:5: C class 'myclass' is declared but not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 11, in <module>
    setup(name="mymodule", ext_modules=cythonize([inumpy_queue]))
  File "site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1096, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args)
  File "site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1219, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: queue/myqueue.pyx
```

I created a small reproducer for the original problem.

```
topdir:
  setup.py
  queue/

queue directory:
  __init__.py
  myqueue.pxd
  myqueue.pyx
```

Files:
setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

inumpy_queue = Extension(
    name="myqueue",
    sources=['queue/myqueue.pyx'],
    language="c++"
)

setup(name="mymodule", ext_modules=cythonize([inumpy_queue]))
```

queue/__init__.py

```
print("called __init__.py")
```

queue/myqueue.pxd

```
# cython: language_level=3
cdef class myclass:
    cdef readonly int data
```

queue/myqueue.pyx

```
# cython: language_level=3

from queue.myqueue import myclass
from queue.myqueue cimport myclass

cdef class myclass:
    def __init__(self, shape):
        print("_____myclass::__init__()")
```

What i'm doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: I had the same issue. And not sure if this is a solution, but I removed the import statements since both the 'pyx' and 'pxd' files are with the same name, just compiled them again, and it worked. Also, this could be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669961/convert-python-object-to-cython-pointer

Answer (score 1):

The following lines should be removed from queue/myqueue.pyx:

```
from queue.myqueue import myclass
from queue.myqueue cimport myclass
```

`cdef` declarations of class fields should be in `pxd` files only.
`def` declarations should be in `pyx` files only.
As your `pyx` and `pxd` files represent one Cython module then it is not necessary to import/cimport `pxd` into `pyx`.

Also, in setup.py extension name should be `queue.myqueue` in order to place Cython module `myqueue` in folder `queue`.

Also, I use `pip install -e .` for building Cython module. After that I can use:

```
from queue.myqueue import myclass
c = myclass(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to distutils. Calling cythonize on the command-line works nicely.

In the pyx importing myqueue.myclass without the package prefix works:

```
from myqueue import myclass
from myqueue cimport myclass
```